# Django deployment issue on Heroku with exact clone of running app: PUSH REJECTED ERROR

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django app on Heroku. I set up another app on the same Heroku account.

Now I want another instance of the first app.

I just cloned the first app and pushed into the newly created app, but it's not working.

Got this error when doing `git push heroku master`

```
        Running setup.py install for distribute
           Before install bootstrap.
           Scanning installed packages
           Setuptools installation detected at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg
           Egg installation
           Patching...
           Renaming /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg into /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg.OLD.1394782343.31
           Patched done.
           Relaunching...
           Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
           NameError: name 'install' is not defined
           Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u57096/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TYqPAN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
           Before install bootstrap.

       Scanning installed packages

       Setuptools installation detected at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg

       Egg installation

       Patching...

       Renaming /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg into /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg.OLD.1394782343.31

       Patched done.

       Relaunching...

       Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

       NameError: name 'install' is not defined

       ----------------------------------------
       Cleaning up...
       Command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_u57096/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-TYqPAN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u57096/distribute
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:gentle-plateau-6569.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:gentle-plateau-6569.git'
```

my requirements.txt file is

```
Django==1.4
South==0.7.5
boto==2.5.2
distribute==0.6.27
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-flash==1.8
django-mailgun==0.2.1
django-registration==0.8
django-session-security==2.0.3
django-sslify==0.2
django-storages==1.1.5
gunicorn==0.14.6
ipdb==0.7
ipython==0.13
newrelic==1.6.0.13
psycopg2==2.4.5
raven==2.0.3
requests==0.13.6
simplejson==2.4.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.7.9
xlwt==0.7.4
```

please help me to get rid of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/91/install-glitch-when-using-pip-virtualenv#comment-5782834).

In other words, `distribute` has been deprecated and is being replaced with `setuptools`. Try replacing the line `distribute==0.6.27` with `setuptools>=0.7` as per the recommendation in the link.

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

you will need to add the following to fix `command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1`, so inside your requirements.txt add this:

> virtualenv==12.0.7